# Posting a Text Status using Facebook API in Android - The simplest method

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have been searching a lot to find a way to do this. But nothing seems to be working for me. Can someone please help in doing this?

This is my image button for facebook status post:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hoributtons"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/facebook"
    android:onClick="shareOnFacebook"
    android:src="@drawable/facebookbutton" />
```

This is my mainactivity.java file's corresponding part:

```
public class MainActivity extends FacebookActivity {

    private static final String APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



public void shareOnFacebook(View v) {
        //mfacebook = new Facebook("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can someone point in the right direction? :)

Comment: what exactly is the question? You're looking for help in writing the body of your postOnWall method?

Comment: Not exactly, edited it now! I tried a lot by googling and similar stackoverflow questions, but nothing worked, so I would need someone to give me a way to post something(text) to the facebook wall! Code for it will be helpful! :)

Comment: still unclear... what exactly are you trying to post and on whose wall? You want the user of your app to invoke some action so that the app can post a message on THEIR wall?

Comment: Oh ok. Actually I have a edittext widget and a button. So if the user clicks the button, the text from the edittext widget should be [posted to that users wall!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you want to post on your own wall (since the question is not clear), this should work for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private Facebook mFacebook;
        private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
        private EditText yourEditText;
        private String toShare;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mFacebook = new Facebook();
            mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
            SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
            SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());
            yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.<youreditTextId>);
            toShare = yourEditText.getText().toString();
        }

        public void shareOnFacebook(View v) {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("message", toShare);

            mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new RequestListener() {
                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {}
                public void onIOException(IOException e) {}
                public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e) {}
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {}
                public void onComplete(String response) {
            }
        }); 

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Posting to your Wall", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

          }

     }
```

For details on posting pictures to wall, [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/) has a good documentation.

Comment: MainActivity extends FacebookActivity? I am extending Activity already.

When I tried this code, I got a non resolved error for "ShareActivity"!
Another question is, what if I am not logged into my facebook? will it open the facebook app for logging in?

Comment: @oDx:I think this link will help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/#step3. I will update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to post message on user`s wall who is successfully login using your android application is(my working code)_

```
public class AndroidFacebookWallPost extends Activity {

// Your Facebook APP ID:
private static String APP_ID = "your App ID here"; //

// Instance of Facebook Class:
private Facebook facebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

// Your ImageButton that Post Message to Facebook Wall:
ImageButton btnPostToWall;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnPostToWall = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);// Your image button...

    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    // set listener for Post Message button
    btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postToWall();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Method that Post a Text Status using Facebook API on user`s wall.
 */
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidFacebookWallPost.this, "Post fail "+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidFacebookWallPost.this, "Post fail due to "+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidFacebookWallPost.this, "Post success.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidFacebookWallPost.this, "Cancle by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

}
```

for more please gone through [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is details of variable that you can out in bundle 
`Bundle params = new Bundle();`

```
params.putString("message", "This string will appear as the status message");
    params.putString("link", "This is the URL to go to");
    params.putString("name", "This will appear beside the picture");
    params.putString("caption", "This will appear under the title");
    params.putString("description", "This will appear under the caption");
    params.putString("picture", "This is the image to appear in the post");
```

And use AsyncFacebookRunner for post data to facebook :

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new RequestListener() {
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {}
            public void onIOException(IOException e) {}
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e) {}
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {}
            public void onComplete(String response) {
        }
    });
```