# Embedded Facebook post dialog in Android.

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Is there a Facebook component for creating posts that can be shown embedded in your application (ie. not leaving your application)?

I've only found components that takes the user away from the application.

Comment: Quick suggestion: The facebook SDK has dialogs which don't force the user to leave the app. I've used them a long while back :) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/ Edit: The FacebookSDK also has a webdialog, might be the same thing (com.facebook.widget.WebDialog)

Comment: Dialog might been a bad choice of words. I would like it to be a component that is visible within an activity.

Comment: How about this? (AsyncFacebookRunner) http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817552/3309883

Comment: @Losin'Me With that solution we need to create the layouts by ourselves for the needed parts. What we want is basically what you get from ShareDialogBuilder but embedded within an activity

Comment: Aww I see, I wish I could help more there, unfortunately I've only heard of those two methods :c

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible with SDK.